# MySQL: fetching an id from an associative table, with specific associations

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've got the following associative table between packages and products (simplified):

```
package_id     product_id    count
1              1             6
1              2             1
1              3             1
2              1             6
2              2             1
3              1             6
4              1             8
4              2             1
```

I'm trying to work out how to create an query which is able to select specific `package_id`'s which contain exactly the products and their counts I supply. So if I'd be trying to find the package that contains: `(product_id = 1 AND count = 6) AND (product_id = 2 AND count = 1)`, it should **only** return `package_id` 2 and not the others, because those contain other products   and / or other counts.

I'd be happy to work this out in my code (PHP) instead of SQL, but since I'm trying to get to the bottom of queries, I'd like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  a.package_ID
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   (a.product_ID = 1 AND a.count = 6) OR
        (a.product_ID = 2 AND a.count = 1)
GROUP   BY a.package_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2 AND
        COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE package_ID = a.package_ID)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8c45/2)

OR

```
SELECT  package_ID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (product_ID, `count`) in ((1, 6), (2, 1))
GROUP   BY package_ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT product_ID, `count`) = 2 AND
        COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE package_ID = a.package_ID)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8c45/4)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply and for the terminology. I'll be trying this out immediately and check if this is the correct answer.

Comment: I noticed, awesome! Just what I needed, thanks! Never knew that you could group WHERE conditions that way, there's a lot for me to learn in SQL. :)